# How to get last updated Facebook ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, etag

How do you only retrieve the "last" updated ads/adsets/campaigns from Facebook via the Ads API? I mean that I need to update on my database only those campaigns/adsets/ads that have changes, not all of them. I've found that a good technique is via facebook etag, but is there any other technique for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filtering` parameter to filter `campaigns`, `adsets` and `ads` on the `updated_time` field.

```
filtering=[{field: "<object>.updated_time", operator: "GREATER_THAN", value: <unix time>}]
```

Using the most recent `unix time` you have saved of the objects you can get all the more recently updated objects. A full curl version to get all `campaigns` updated after `2018-02-01`:

```
curl -G \
-d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
-d 'filtering=[{field:"campaign.updated_time",operator:"GREATER_THAN",value:1517443200}]' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/campaigns'
```

Note: I could only get [`unix time`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to work and have no idea if there is another format that is supported by the API

Comment: Do you know what causes a campaign's updated_time to change? I added a new ad to a Campaign but the updated time remained unchanged...

Comment: maybe as you performed an ad level change (new ad + assign to campaign) the updated_time of that ad should be checked, not of the campaign?